# Adobe ColdFusion 9 won't start with NewRelic agent

Tags: java, coldfusion, newrelic

I'm running an Adobe Coldfusion 9 server with IIS on a Windows Server 2003 box, but when I installed the New Relic agent per the instructions now the ColdFusion service refuses to start. 
The coldfusion-out.log contains the following:

```
Feb 18, 2013 23:34:41 -0500 NewRelic 1 INFO: Agent is using Logback
Feb 18, 2013 23:34:42 -0500 NewRelic 1 INFO: Loading configuration file "C:\newrelic\.\newrelic.yml"
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at jrunx.kernel.JRun.invoke(JRun.java:180)
at jrunx.kernel.JRun.main(JRun.java:168)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.jrunx.kernel)
at     java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
at jrunx.kernel.JRun.<init>(JRun.java:446)
at jrunx.kernel.JRun$1.run(JRun.java:346)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at jrunx.kernel.JRun.start(JRun.java:343)
at jrunx.kernel.JRun.startByNTService(JRun.java:427)
... 6 more
```

I don't think it is file permissions on the folder since I gave permissions to the IIS user. But I'm at a loss as to how to troubleshoot this.

Any other ColdFusion people have run into this problem with New Relic?

Thanks

PS: This is running on a VPS, not a full dedicated server.

Comment: I am not familiar with NewRelic but that path seems a bit odd; "C:\newrelic\.\newrelic.yml".  Is that correct?

Comment: yeah, that seemed odd to me; c:\newrelic is the directory where the jar and the related files are located; and there is a newrelic.yml there with some config info. The docs say that the jar looks for newrelic.yml on the same directory where it (the jar) is located.

Comment: You said you gave permissions to the IIS user but what about the ColdFusion user?

Comment: I've just tried it and getting same error message. I can't seem to find any reference to the issue anywhere. Still digging though.

Comment: FYI, I've made a support request to New Relic on the issue. Hopefully they can give us some pointers :)

Comment: Check to see if the log files in the location specified in newrelic.yml are being written to (in your case C:\newrelic\logs would be the default folder). If they are being written then the configuration file is being read, but you lack the permission specified in the error: java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.jrunx.kernel. See my answer below to correct than.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toby at New Relic support here: currently the New Relic agent isn't able to instrument Adobe Coldfusion 9 server with IIS. If you use Coldfusion with the Java app server, we can instrument that system, but it does look like:

1) Coldfusion with IIS won't capture accurate data with the New Relic agent

2) the New Relic agent interferes with Coldfusion starting up correctly

For the moment, I would recommend un-installing the New Relic agent from that framework. I'll work this up into a feature request so that we can see support for this framework in a future release.

Comment: Thanks Toby for the answer. We are planning to move this app to an Apache/Tomcat7 environment (still running ColdFusion as a webapp). Hopefully we'll have better luck then.

Comment: Just to confirm that the combination of CF902 - Java 6 - JRun - IIS and the latest New Relic agent ( 2.20 ) fails to install with the error reported by the OP above. However, I've been using New Relic successfully in that environment up to New Relic agent 2.09. and still am, actually.

Comment: @VincentBuck Did you try making the change listed in my answer?

Comment: @WhiteKnight: Yep. No luck

Answer (score 2):

I've just tested running New Relic with ColdFusion 7 on JRun 4 using Java 6 with IIS on Windows Server 2003 and it works fine. I think the confusion was that even though IIS is hosting the web page, JRun is a Java app server, which is running ColdFusion.

In your `java.policy` (the `java.home` listed in `jrun\bin\jvm.config` file) add the following permission (and any other required permissions that appear after adding this one)

```
grant {
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.jrunx.kernel";
}
```

Comment: This will do the trick, but there a few more. As of now that is what I had to change.


In C:\coldfusion9\runtime\jre\lib\security\java.policy added this block to the bottom.


`grant {
   permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.jrunx.kernel";
 permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getServerJNDIContext";
 permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getServerIdentity";
};`


Use c:\coldfusion9\bin\cfstart.bat to see the output easily. Look for java.lang.RuntimePermsission xxxxx type error messages and add lines.

Comment: Although this will get the JVM reporting, transactions do not appear to be. IIS connects to JRUN via a weird connector dll. Guessing new relic is having an issue getting at the servlet calls.

Comment: @EricTwilegar Yes I had to add a few permissions, but wasn't sure if they also applied to ColdFusion 9. I had only enough time to get it working, but haven't had enough time to test it properly. I might try again this week and will see if I can get transactions. Though you may have to use custom instrumentation (https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/custom-instrumentation-with-the-java-agent) or custom XML (https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/custom-monitoring-by-xml).

Comment: One more thing to mention here: Make sure that the CF user is allowed to read the java.policy file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with cf9 and lodged a ticket with newRelic (actually, the sales guy I was talking to did that for me). Their answer below:

> Hi there Christophe -
>
> I hate to be the bringer of badnews, but there's no support for Coldfusion running in IIS > with any agent at this time. I have made a feature request for you though. I've also >attached this ticket to the request so that if and when we implement it, we'll contact you directly.
>
> I'm going to go ahead and mark this ticket as "closed", but if you have any other > questions, just reply to the ticket and it'll open back up and alert me.
>
> Cheers,
>   Frank.

Note that the newRelic agent works fine on CF10 over IIS.